# ¿Cómo hacer que Hibernate cree las tablas de la BBDD?

Tags: java, hibernate, tablas

a ver me han pasado un proyecto el cual integra Hibernate, pero no me han pasado la base de datos. en el MySql Workbench, he creado la base de de datos, pero no se como hacer para que al arrancar el proyecto, hibernate me creé las tablas.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En el apartado de hibernate-configuration  puedes agregarle este código. Una vez hayas creado la base de datos, puedes borrar dicha línea.

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```